# como puedo extraer el codigo a una funcion?

Tags: reactjs

quisiera poder extraer el codigo del return que es un buscador y ponerlo en una funcion, e provado varias maneras pero no se llamar a la funcion para poder luego mapear.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTitle, setSearchTitle] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      );
      setPosts(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadPosts();
  }, []);



return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Search Filter</h3>
      <input
        style={{ width: "30%", height: "25px" }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      {loading ? (
        <h4>Loading ...</h4>
      ) : (
        posts
          .filter((value) => {
            if (searchTitle === "") {
              return value;
            } else if (
              value.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle.toLowerCase())
            ) {
              return value;
            }
          })
          .map((item) => <h5 key={item.id}>{item.title}</h5>)
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Te refieres a que quieres hacer tu código más granular y separado?
Creo que podrías seccionarlo así:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

// search filter component - separado
function SearchFilter({ value, onFilterChange }) {
  return (
    <div className="search-filter">
      <h3>Search Filter</h3>
      <input
        value={value}
        style={{ width: '30%', height: '25px' }}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => onFilterChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// hook para cargar los posts - separado del componente
function usePosts() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      );
      setPosts(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadPosts();
  }, []);

  return { loading, posts };
}

// posts component - separado
function Posts() {
  const [searchTitle, setSearchTitle] = useState('');
  const { loading, posts } = usePosts(); // usa el hook de los posts
  
  // filtra los posts
  const filter = searchTitle.toLowerCase().trim();
  const filteredPosts = posts.filter((value) => {
    if (!searchTitle) return true;
    return value.title.toLowerCase()
      .includes(filter);
  });

  return (
    <div className="posts-container">
      {/* Usa SearchFilter component */}
      <SearchFilter value={searchTitle}
                    onFilterChange={setSearchTitle} />
      {/* Renderiza los posts */}
      {loading ? (
        <h4>Loading ...</h4>
      ) : (
        filteredPosts.map((item) =>
          <h5 key={item.id}>{item.title}</h5>)
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Posts />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```